# Ruby `ensure` is not running

Tags: ruby

I have a simple method running in a private method in my model :

```
def with_time_zone(zone)
  @old_time_zone = Time.zone
  Time.zone = self.account.timezone
  Chronic.time_class = Time.zone
  yield
ensure
  Time.zone = @old_time_zone
  Chronic.time_class = @old_time_zone
end
```

I use it like this :

```
with_time_zone(account.timezone) do
  Time.parse(@time)
end
```

However, when I run my tests, the begin with the timezone set to EST, but when it comes time to compare the times, the `Time.zone` will be set to which ever timezone was last used in that block. Thus telling me that the `ensure` method isn't being called, and the Time.zone is not being reset.

Anyone know why this might be occurring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps, you are making nested calls to the method? Since you don't maintain a stack, the first nested call will cause the earlier value of `@old_time_zone` to be lost.

If that's what's going on, just stop using an instance variable, and use a local variable instead (no `@` sign). Each nested invocation of the method has its own local variables, and they're still in scope in the `ensure` block.

Answer (score 3):

```
def with_time_zone(zone)
  old_time_zone = Time.zone
  Chronic.time_class = Time.zone = zone
  yield
ensure
  Chronic.time_class = Time.zone = old_time_zone
end

with_time_zone(account.timezone) do
  Time.parse(some_time)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not enough to check the value of `Time.zone` as something else might have changed it after ensure has run..

to isolate the problem, try to have a message in the ensure block to make sure it has run or not